# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when sorting a DataGridView using a custom IComparer

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, indexoutofboundsexception

### Setup

I have a piece of code that is sorting a DataGridView using a custom IComparer:

```
public class CustomComparer: IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        DataGridViewRow row2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

        if (row1.ReadOnly && row2.ReadOnly)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (row1.ReadOnly && !row2.ReadOnly)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
}
```

### Problem

Strangely, when I execute the following line (after populating the rows):

```
grid.Sort(new CustomComparer());
```

I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException with the message "Index was out of range. Parameter: index".

### More Facts

Further investigation revealed the following:

- The DataGridView I'm sorting *doesn't* have a BindingSource on it - rows have been manually added.
- The Stack Trace of the error is only one level deep - it occurs on an InternalDictionary in mscorlib
- Strange fact #1 - This only happens if at any point, my custom comparer returns -1 for any of its comparisons
- If I change the Sort method to no longer use my CustomComparer, the exception is not thrown.

### Workaround

This last fact led me to rewrite the Compare() method to defer to .NET's CompareTo method:

```
DataGridViewRow row1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
DataGridViewRow row2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

return row1.ReadOnly.CompareTo(row2.ReadOnly);
```

Which mysteriously **worked**. The exception is no longer thrown.

So although I have a workaround, I wonder if anyone has any idea why this could possibly be a fix, and what the issue might have been in the first place. I've looked at the implementation of CompareTo and it *also* returns -1...

Comment: You're returning -1 when both have ReadOnly of false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

juharr is right, but here's *why* he's right:

Your implementation of `Compare` is not symmetric, meaning if `row1.ReadOnly == false` and `row2.ReadOnly == false` you return `-1`, meaning "`row1` is *less than* `row2`".  If you turn that comparison around with the same values, then `row2` becomes *less than* `row1`.  This is likely confusing the sort algorithm that requires `Compare` to be symmetric.

The correct comparison should be:

```
    if (row1.ReadOnly == row2.ReadOnly)  // change && to ==
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (row1.ReadOnly && !row2.ReadOnly)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
```

which is likely what `bool.CompareTo(bool)` would return, which is why your "workaround" (which is a better solution, in my opinion) works.

Comment: Thanks, I'd spotted the asymmetry but hadn't considered that it could be the cause of an index out of range exception. During my investigation I did rewrite the method to just return -1, to make sure that was the issue. Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are returning `-1` when both have `ReadOnly` of `false`.  You should return `0` in that case.

Just change your first if statement to

```
 if((row1.ReadOnly && row2.ReadOnly) || !(row1.ReadOnly || row2.ReadOnly))
```